# Create sharing link MS Graph BadRequest

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to get a sharing link from MS Graph API but it doesn't work.
I'm connecting to company OneDrive.

```
internal async Task<string> GetDowloadLink(string fileName, string filePath)
        {
            var type = "view"; //read only link

            var scope = "anonymous"; //anyone can access

            Permission permission = await graphServiceClient.Users[oneDriveUserId].Drive.Root
                .ItemWithPath(filePath + "\\" + fileName)
                .CreateLink(type, scope, null, null, null)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();

            return permission.Link.WebUrl;
        }
```

Request always returns:

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
```

I have similar method for deleting a file and it works OK.